# Rails/Sphinx: search excerpts are also showing search conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

This gives the results I was expecting:

```
result = Content.search("minerva", :conditions => {:publication_code => "12345678"})

result.first.element_type #=> "chapter"

result.first.excerpts.text #=> "outdated practice, The Owl of <span class=\"match\">Minerva</span> talks about the “unrealistic ‘Cartesian &#8230;  major premise The Owl of <span class=\"match\">Minerva</span> details the innumerable combinations possible &#8230;  concepts?” See The Owl of <span class=\"match\">Minerva</span>, p. 319. “Of course, ideally"
```

However: if I'm including search conditions that are literally present in the text, for instance the word "section" (which is a content element type) this is what I'm getting:

```
result = Content.search("minerva", :conditions => {:publication_code => "12345678", :element_type => "section"})

result.first.element_type #=> "section"

result.first.excerpts.text #=> "November 2001. The Owl of <span class=\"match\">Minerva</span>, p. 107. provides as follows: &#8230;  foreign diplomatic or consular property, <span class=\"match\">section</span> 177 would place the United &#8230;  source of leverage. In addition, <span class=\"match\">section</span> 177 could seriously affect our"
```

"Section", literally, is now also considered a match. I'm not getting what's the cause of this response.

**Update to illustrate the problem some more:**

Here's a query that finds a search term ("certification") near the term I'm using in the search conditions ("section", to limit my search to `element_type`s that are sections).

```
result = Content.search("certification", :conditions => {:publication_code => "12345678", :element_type => "section"})
```

The text that gets returned is this (shortened to match following excerpts, and bold text mine):

```
result.first.text
```

> […] and operation of **section** 10 and the **section** 10 **certification** process. He noted […]
>
> […] object of the **certification** procedure introduced by **section** 10(1)(b) was not to […]
>
> […] domestic court. The **certification** procedure provided for by **section** 10 is similarly […]

Calling `result.first.excerpts.text` gives me the following. As you can see, everywhere in the text where either the term 'classification' or 'section' is found, it's set as a match.

```
" &#8230; and operation of <span class=\"match\">section</span> 10 and the <span class=\"match\">section</span> 10 <span class=\"match\">certification</span> process. He noted: &#8230;  object of the <span class=\"match\">certification</span> procedure introduced by <span class=\"match\">section</span> 10(1)(b) was not to &#8230;  domestic court. The <span class=\"match\">certification</span> procedure provided for by <span class=\"match\">section</span> 10 is similarly &#8230; "
```

Answer (score 1):

The excerpts pane uses all query terms when generating output - which includes supplied conditions (as they end up being part of the Sphinx query - e.g. your second example, from Sphinx's perspective, is `"minerva @publication_code 12345678 @element_type section"`).

An alternative is to have your own excerpter with just the query you want:

```
excerpter = ThinkingSphinx::Excerpter.new 'content_core', 'minerva', {}
excerpter.excerpt! results.first.text
```

The first argument when building the excerpter is the index name, the second is the search query to match against, and the third is [options](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-2.1.5.html#api-func-buildexcerpts).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just a coincidence. 
Try with a dataset that doesn't have `section` in the text to see if this also happens.

Comment: It doesn't include "section" (as a word) where it isn't found in the text, but all occasions where it is found, it's included in the excerpt. I edited my question to illustrate this.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry, I misunderstood the question then :)